# numeric format on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need your expertise on my problem

```
SELECT 
(begBal) AS 'Beg. Balance',
(deposit) AS 'Deposit',
(withdrawal) AS 'Withdrawn',
(begBal+deposit-withdrawal) AS Balance
FROM savingsTable;
```

result:

```
| Beg. Balance | Deposit | Withdrawal | Balance | 
|         2000 |    1500 |       1100 |    2400 |
```

our teacher wants the result like this :

```
| Beg. Balance |  Deposit | Withdrawal |  Balance |
|     2,000.00 | 1,500.00 |   1,100.00 | 2,400.00 |
```

please include a little explanation on your answer. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: With respect, this is described in detail in the MySQL manual, where you can look.  A core part of studying IT is learning to use the documentation and resources.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: @Ollie. in our MySQL class we didn't reach this topic yet. i'm reading the ebooks and tutorials and testing it on my laptop. sometimes i get confused on some terminology (cant comprehend some deep english but im learning) so sometimes i prefer samples. thanks for your time, i will read that book after my MySQL 101 book. thanks for answering sir ollie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that these are decimal fields.  If not, it doesn't really make sense to have the `.00` since it can't be stored.  Either way, just add `FORMAT(field, 2)`, e.g.

```
SELECT FORMAT(begBal, 2) AS 'Beg. Balance',
```

Comment: thank you for answering sir Explosion. and thank you for making my code as a sample. it really give me quick idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FORMAT()`

```
SELECT FORMAT(columnName, 2)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8372/2)

SOURCE:

- [MySQL FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Comment: what is lacking with the answer?

Comment: you're answer is good sir JW, it just that im confuse on how to use it because you dont use the code as example. sorry im really new to mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function to do this.